# Rails attributes headache

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

newbie rails question coming up.

I have a class like this:

```
class Thing < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :name
    attr_accessor :name
    validates_uniqueness_of :name, :case_sensitive => false
end
```

I have done a migration and the table looks okay. I then fire up the `rails console` and try the following:

```
t = Thing.new(:name => "test")
=> #<Thing id: nil, name: nil, description: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
```

already here it says name is nil, why?
Continuing on, I try this:

```
t.name
 => "test"
```

Now name seems to be set anyway?
If I try to save:

```
t.save!
Thing Exists (8.0ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "things" WHERE LOWER("things"."name") = LOWER('test') LIMIT 1
SQL (16.0ms)  INSERT INTO "things" ("created_at", "description", "name", "updated_at") VALUES ('2012-10-28 16:10:12.701000', NULL, NULL, '2012-10-28 16:10:12.701000')
=> true
```

Why is the name I have specified not being saved?
What I want is to be able to specify attributes as a hash when calling new and then save the instance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should remove `attr_accessor :name`, this create getter & setter for `name`, but they are already created by ActiveRecord

Comment: Spot on. To expound on this answer, you only need `attr_accessor` when you want a 'virtual attribute' that isn't persisted to the database. ActiveRecord automatically creates the `#name` and `#name=` methods for you if you have a `name` field in your table.