# Parameters from rails form not saved in database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, forms

As my log file shows, when you submit a form in my app, the parameters are being established correctly, but they are not saving in my database.  This is only happening with two parameters, which are used with a dropdown form.

Here is my logger:

```
Processing by UsersController#create as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"tIdsWBUB+ik8eeOOxUEQs9mSB/WiSyX2Gkw3/fAw64w=", "user"=>   {"name"=>"Jeffgo", "email"=>"JeffreyEricKatz6@gmail.com", "cell_number"=>"5554595515", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]", "day_open"=>"0", "time_open"=>"14"}, "commit"=>"Create my account"}

RecordedLesson Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "recorded_lessons".* FROM "recorded_lessons" LIMIT 1
(0.1ms)  SELECT 1 FROM "users" WHERE LOWER("users"."email") = LOWER('JeffreyEricKatz6@gmail.com') LIMIT 1

Binary data inserted for `string` type on column `password_digest`
SQL (51.2ms)  INSERT INTO "users" ("cell_number", "created_at", "day_open", "email",    "last_class", "name", "password_digest", "recorded_lesson_id", "test", "time_available", "time_open", "type", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["cell_number", "2154997415"], ["created_at", Sun, 28 Oct 2012 16:45:50 EDT -04:00], ["day_open", nil], ["email", "jeffreyerickatz6@gmail.com"], ["last_class", 0], ["name", "Jeffgo"], ["password_digest", "$2a$10$Idl8H7tMvotqhwiFteya2eSUaNEdAPNU6dqrp5PPalEyfo7w6x5gq"], ["recorded_lesson_id", 1], ["test", nil], ["time_available", nil], ["time_open", nil], ["type", nil], ["updated_at", Sun, 28 Oct 2012 16:45:50 EDT -04:00]]'
```

Ok, now here is the part of the form:
    <% provide(:title, "Sign up") %>

## Sign up

```
<div class="row">
<div class="span6 offset3">
<%= simple_form_for @user do |f| %>
<%= render 'shared/user_error_messages' %>

<%= f.label :name %>
<%= f.text_field :name %>

<%= f.label :email %>
<%= f.text_field :email %>

<%= f.label :cell_number %>
<%= f.text_field :cell_number, :hint => '5555555555' %>

<%= f.label :password %><br />
<%= f.password_field :password %>


<%= f.label :password_confirmation, "Confirmation" %><br />
<%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %>

<%= f.label :day_open %> <br />
<%= f.select("day_open", {"Sunday" => "0", "Monday" => "1", "Tuesday" => "2", "Wednesday" => "3", "Thursday" => "4", "Friday" => "5", "Saturday" => "6"}) %>

<%= f.label :time_open %> <br />
<%= f.select("time_open", {"7:30 pm" => "14", "8:30 pm" => "15", "9:30 pm" => "16"}) %>
<div class="actions">
 <%= f.submit "Create my account" %>
 </div>

 <% end %>

 </div>
 </div>
```

My controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
def new
  @title = "Sign up"
  @user = User.new 
end


def create
 @user = User.new(params[:user])
 if @user.save
   flash[:success] = "Welcome to the Sample App!"
   redirect_to @user
  else
    @title = "Sign up"
    render 'new'
  end
 end
end
```

finally, here is my model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :tutoring_sessions
belongs_to :recorded_lesson
attr_accessor :day_open, :time_open
attr_accessible :name, :email, :cell_number, :password, :password_confirmation, 
    :day_open, :time_open, :tutoring_sessions_attributes, :recorded_lesson_id
has_secure_password
accepts_nested_attributes_for :tutoring_sessions, :allow_destroy => true

before_save { |user| user.email = email.downcase }

validates :name, length: { maximum: 50 }
VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
validates :email,  format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX }, 
uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false}
validates :password, presence: true, length: { minimum: 6}, on: :create
validates :password_confirmation, presence: true, on: :create
after_initialize :init

def init
  self.recorded_lesson_id ||= RecordedLesson.first.id
  self.last_class ||= 0
end

def advance
    if self[:recorded_lesson_id] == nil
        self[:recorded_lesson_id] = RecordedLesson.first.id
    else
        self[:recorded_lesson_id] += 1
    end
    #self.save
end





    def nows_weekday 
        @todays_weekday = Time.now.utc.wday
    end

    def number_of_days_from_now
        (selected_day - nows_weekday)
    end



    def is_student?
        self[:type] == 1
     end

   def is_tutor?
       self[:type] == 0
   end

   def set_day_and_time_available
      set_hour = Time.now.utc.change(:hour => selected_time)
      set_day  = set_first_day_of_session(set_hour)
      self[:time_available] ||= set_day.to_datetime
   end

   def set_first_day_of_session(set_hour)
       if selected_day > nows_weekday #(Eg. Today is Tuesday and chooses wednesday)
       first_day_of_session= set_hour.advance(:days => number_of_days_from_now)
       else #(Eg. Today is Tuesday and chooses Monday)
          first_day_of_session= set_hour.advance(:days => (number_of_days_from_now + 7))
       end
   end
 end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove the line `attr_accessor :day_open, :time_open`
It's overriding, existing accessors created by `ActiveRecord`

this is the same issue than [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13110573/rails-attributes-headache)